# how to use multiple url RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is working

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)\.html$ detail.php?category=$1&model=$2
```

this is working

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)\.html$ brand.php?brand=$1
```

this is not working

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)\.htm$ colour.php?colour=$8
```

only two rule working how to use multiple rewrite rule using .htaccess

Comment: You've only got one `()`-set in your last example, so why/how should $8 ever be populated?

Comment: And hyphen in the middle is wrong make it `RewriteRule ^([\w\s-]+)\.htm$ colour.php?colour=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Marc B@ i was try with $1 but not working thats why i change it but $8  also not working

Comment: anubhava@ i change code but not working page is open empty

Comment: Are you getting 404 or some other error, provide details. What URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: not 404 error only header and footer is showing and data is not showing

Comment: Still relevant details are missing from your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63361/discussion-between-user1796164-and-anubhava).

Comment: if i use like this ^colour/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)\.htm$ colour.php?colour=$1 then it is working with out colour/ this it is not working

Answer (score 0):

> if i use like this `^colour/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)\.htm$ colour.php?colour=$1` then it is working with out `colour/` this it is not working

This problem seems to be due to enabling of `MultiViews`. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To disable this use this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^colour/([\w\s-]+)\.htm$ colour.php?colour=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: if i paste this Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / it is stop working and if i use colour/ then my all page url showing like this  http://www.example.com/data/colour/images/logo.jpg but i have a logo file in data/image folder this is the problem in all page link

Comment: Your comment is not making any sense. Post your complete .htaccess by editing your question also provide what full URL did you enter in your browser